# Disable SharePoint Mobile in Office 365

Tags: mobile

I created a responsive SharePoint site that works well for both Desktop and Mobile versions.

The problem is that SharePoint automatically redirects mobile devices to the "Mobile" URL, which is something like:

```
http://mysite/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx
```

I know that it's possible to disable this in Farm solutions, but does anyone know how to do this in SharePoint Online?

If not possible, is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally wrote a script that appends "mobile=0" to all links relative to the site collection.

```
function fixMobileLinks {
    var qMobile = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString()["mobile"];
    if (qMobile == "0") {
        var siteCollectionUrl = "http://mySiteCol";
        var jLink = 'a[href*="' + siteCollectionUrl + '"]';

        $("#s4-workspace").on("click", jLink, function () {
            var $link = $(this);                
            var href = $link.attr('href');
            href = updateQueryStringParameter(href, "mobile", "0");
            location.href = href;
            return false;           
        });
    }
}

function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re)) {
        return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    }
    else {
        return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only answer I can find is:

> To achieve the goal, please change “?mobile=1” to “?mobile=0” at the
>   end the URL on mobile device.  For example, to access the default
>   homepage of a SharePoint public website without mobile version, please
>   change “....com/Pages/default.aspx?mobile=1”
>   to “....com/Pages/default.aspx?mobile=0”

Source: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/13897/63610.aspx#63610

Now if there is anyone WHO can make a script that is loaded on the page that changes the "1" to a "0", or figure out another solution, that would help a lot.

/Ulrich

Comment: Yes, I finally had to write that script, thanks for the update. I'll post the solution here.