# How can I show desktop version as default on mobile/tablet in Sharepoint Online/365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile

Microsoft says that this isn't possible, but I'm sure there is a workaround of some kind out there. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you can apply Mobile Device channels to Office 365 which is a 2013 feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733517.aspx

If that doesn't work then try appending ismobile=0 to the URL on mobile devices.  Hope this helps!

[Disable SharePoint Mobile in Office 365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58928/disable-sharepoint-mobile-in-office-365)