# Fully Disabling Mobile View for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, mobile

I am using the [Responsive-UI Package](https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-2016) for Sharepoint Online (Office 365). Because of this more responsive framework, I would like to fully disable the OOTB mobile view so our iPad users do not have to "**switch to PC view**" upon arriving at our site(s).

Despite disabling the Mobile Browser View through the following:

**Site Settings > Site Features > Mobile Browser View [DISABLED]**

I am still seeing the mobile view intermittently. Is there additional configuration to fully remove this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the goal, please change “?mobile=1” to “?mobile=0” at the end the URL on mobile device. here is the client script someone wrote for the same:

```
function fixMobileLinks {
    var qMobile = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString()["mobile"];
    if (qMobile == "0") {
        var siteCollectionUrl = "http://mySiteCol";
        var jLink = 'a[href*="' + siteCollectionUrl + '"]';

        $("#s4-workspace").on("click", jLink, function () {
            var $link = $(this);                
            var href = $link.attr('href');
            href = updateQueryStringParameter(href, "mobile", "0");
            location.href = href;
            return false;           
        });
    }
}

function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re)) {
        return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    }
    else {
        return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

[Disable SharePoint Mobile in Office 365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58928/disable-sharepoint-mobile-in-office-365)